# Concatenate POSIX file paths from a list

Tags: applescript, posix, rsync

I have a **list with folder paths** who should concatenate correctly to have **multiple sourcefolders** backed up into a single source folder with the **`rsync`** command.

---

This is what I have so far:

```
set sourcefolderlist to {"/Volumes/sourcefolder1", "/Volumes/sourcefolder2"}
set localfolder to quoted form of POSIX path of ("/Users/dfdfdf/destinationfolder")

set allSourceFolders to ""
repeat with oneSourceFolder in sourcefolderlist
    set allSourceFolders to ((quoted form of POSIX path of allSourceFolders) & oneSourceFolder)
end repeat
```

so the source-paths should be in a list which concatenate with **POSIX file paths** (like `localfolder`).
The end should look this:

```
do shell script "rsync -arvuE " & allSourceFolders & " " & localfolder
```

How can I concatenate the items in `sourcefolderlist` so that `rsync` can read the correct POSIX folder paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page:

```
rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST
```

I think you just separate them with a " " character.

If you still need a list as *source of all sources* (comes in handy), loop thru it like this:

```
set sourcefolderlist to {"/Volumes/sourcefolder1", "/Volumes/sourcefolder2"}
set localfolder to quoted form of POSIX path of ("/Users/dfdfdf/destinationfolder")

set sources to ""
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in sourcefolderlist
    set sources to sources & " " & quoted form of (item i of sourcefolderlist as text)
end repeat

log sources -- > (* '/Volumes/sourcefolder1' '/Volumes/sourcefolder2'*)

do shell script "rsync -arvuE " & sources & " " & localfolder
```

BTW: use AppleScript's built-in code snippets: make a new line, paste "sourcefolderlist" (=the variable containing the list) into the new line and CTRL-Click it. Select "Repeat Routines" and from there "Process every item".

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Applescript Script library ( [Join list items v2](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/join-list-items-v2/) ) to help with joining Applescript list items in which  you can also add quotes to the items as they are placed in the final string.

Example of use in this case would be:

```
        #Needed Use Clauses
    use script "you Library name here"
    --use scripting additions

    set sourcefolderlist to {"/Volumes/sourcefolder1", "/Volumes/sourcefolder2"}
    set sources to join list items sourcefolderlist using text space with items in single quotes

-- Result--> "'/Volumes/sourcefolder1' '/Volumes/sourcefolder2'"
```

Also a small [explanation about the library (v1)](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/applescript-script-libraries-text-utils-command-join-list-items/) in the post for version 1. Which also has links to Apples sessions on Applescript Script Libraries